# boundary of A open or closed?

Tags: general-topology

My professor asked this question :

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and let $A \subset X$. If $A$ is both open and closed, can $\partial A$ be open ? Is $\partial A$ closed ?

Obviously, if $A$ is open and closed we have $int(A) = cl(A) = A$ thus $\partial A = \emptyset$.

Also, regardless of $A$, we have $\partial A = cl(A) \setminus int(A) = cl(A) \cap cl(X \setminus A)$ so the boundary is always closed.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. The professor is just training you not to overlook trivial possibilities. You were expected to realize that the boundary was empty in this case. If you want a more challenging question, is it possible for the boundary of an arbitrary set $A$ to be non-empty and open?